# How to remove special character filename in Linux?

Tags: linux, rm

I have a filename with `-v`. I try to remove it by

```
rm -v or rm "-v" or rm ¥-v
```

But it shows something like

```
rm: missing operand
Try 'rm --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Try `rm \-v`..,

Comment: Not a programming question; [unix.se]? [su]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a filename with `-v`

Try:

```
rm -- '-v'
```

If you need to use `rm` option like verbose for example, try:

```
rm -v -- '-v'
```

`--` tells SHELL it's the end of options. And disables further option processing. So anything after `--` will be treated as filenames.